# Azure AD Authentication redirect access denied to static page (.Net Core + Vue)

Tags: c#, vue.js, .net-core, azure-active-directory

I have trouble to setup Authentication on the web application (.Net Core and Vue.js) to redirect to the static page when the logged user has no access to the application.

appsettings.json:

```
"AzureAd": {
"Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
"Domain": "xxx.onmicrosoft.com",
"TenantId": "xxx-c519-4651-b8c4-xxx",
"ClientId": "xxx-a3f5-4e77-9427-xxx",
"CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
```

},

Startup.cs/ConfigureServices

```
// cookie policy 
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        // azure AD auth
        if (applicationFeatures.SsoAuthenticationEnabled ?? false)
        {
            // adding authentication with Azure Ad
            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

            services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(
                AzureADDefaults.CookieScheme,
                options => options.AccessDeniedPath = "/home/AccessDenied");

            // enable cross-origin requests from microsoft login plaftorm
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                var azureADOptions = Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd").Get<AzureADOptions>();
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder.WithOrigins(azureADOptions.Instance)
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowCredentials());
                
            });
        }

        // add controllers and vue.js project root
        services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = applicationFeatures.StaticFilesDirectory;
        });
```

Startup.cs/Configure

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
        app.UseMiddleware<AuthorizationMiddleware>();           

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
            else
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "dist";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseVueCli(npmScript: "serve");
            }

        });
```

And when I logged in as a user, which is not assigned to the registered app in Azure, I see this error
[image: Exception]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

work around

1. Change the ‘User assignment required’  to No  by navigating to properties under enterprise applications and save it.
2. Go to the App Registration portal and grant the admin consent .

[Reference 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/error-code-aadsts50105-user-not-assigned-role) ,
[Reference 2](https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2020/01/receiving-error-aadsts50105-the-signed-in-user-emailhidden-is-not-assigned-to-a-role-for-the-application/)